# Java used heap vs. allocated object size

Tags: java, profiling, heap-memory, constraint-programming

I have one probably dumb question. I am currently testing CSP solvers choco and jacop. When I run profiling of the app (graph colouring, about 3000 nodes), I dont fully understand the results.

The used heap space declared by profiler is about 1GB of memory. The sum of all object created is less than 100MB. Where are the other 900MB of RAM?

I think that method calls (solvers probably use massive backtracking) are being alocated on stack, so here should not be the problem. When I reduce maximum memory by using Xmx param, the app fails with exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

So it seems, that the rest isnt unused uncollected memory (because in this case the GC would dealocate it (and would not fail)).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any kind of filter on the Allocated Object Size visualizer?  What profiler are you using? Also please paste the results of your profiler if the data is not sensetive.

Comment: I am using netbeans profiler - http://img405.imageshack.us/i/profilerd.png/ the last point of used memory is 374MB (still much more than in allocated objects)...

Comment: At the peak (in live results), the biggest array has about 30MB (everything else is proportionally smaller)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Amir Afghani was probably correct in his comment**. The classes (objects) in Netbeans 6.9.1 are probably somehow filtered (?or the profiler is bogus?), because when I performed the heap dump from java visual VM and analyzed it, it showed me !very! different numbers (which were in sum the same as the used heap).

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: It's probably not bogus, it's most likely filtered somehow not to show Strings, or char[]'s, or something or other...

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a map of the heap?  Most likely it's fragmented so those 100M of objects are spread out across the entire memory space.  The memory needed is both a function of allocated objects and how fast they're being allocated and then de-referenced.  That error means the memory area is too small for the work load, the garbage collector is consuming a lot CPU managing it, and it went beyond the allowed threshold.

Comment: In java this should not be the cause... On eden its impossible to fragment memory (there are two spaces, one of them always free, and everything is copied during collection)...and in tenured generation, GC is shaking (dont know the proper english word) the objects together (and defragmenting the memory)...